# performance considerations get() in data.table

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I've been using get() in a loop to manipulate a column j by i with reference to multiple other columns.

I wonder if there is a faster/more efficient way? Any performance considerations?

Here a minimal example of the type of operation I have in mind:

```
require(data.table) # version 1.12.8
dt = data.table(v1=c(1,2,NA),v2=c(0,0,1),v3=c(0,0,0))
for (i in 1:2){
     dt[ is.na(get(paste0('v',i))), (paste0('v',i)):= get(paste0('v',i+1))+2 ][]
}
```

The actual tables I do this with are much larger (~5 mio rows, ~300 columns).

I'd highly appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: try to use apply function for larger data, it would use less memory space than loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `set` which would assign in place

```
library(data.table)
for(j in 1:2) {
    i1 <- which(is.na(dt[[j]]))
    set(dt, i = i1, j = j, value = dt[[j+1]][i1]+ 2)
 }

dt
#   v1 v2 v3
#1:  1  0  0
#2:  2  0  0
#3:  3  1  0
```

---

There is not much difference between a `for` loop or `lapply`if both are using the `get`.  For performace improvement, it is better to use `set`

---

In `base R`, we can also do

```
setDF(dt)
i1 <- is.na(dt[-length(dt)])
dt[-length(dt)][i1] <- dt[-1][i1] + 2
dt
#  v1 v2 v3
#1  1  0  0
#2  2  0  0
#3  3  1  0
```

Comment: this seems to work, thanks. admittedly didn't know that set() takes vectors as argument i ..

Answer (score 2):

Yes your `for` loop slows you down considerably. Even a simple `lapply` (and there's probably more elegant ways to do), brings you significant performance gains:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(v1 = rnorm(100), v2 = sample(c(NA,1:5)), v3 = sample(c(NA,1:5)), v4 = sample(c(NA,1:5)))
dt2 <- copy(dt)
dt3 <- copy(dt)
dt4 <- copy(dt)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  for (i in 1:2){
    dt[ is.na(get(paste0('v',i))), (paste0('v',i)):= get(paste0('v',i+1))+2 ]
  },
  for (i in 1:2){ 
    dt2[ is.na(get(paste0('v',i))), (paste0('v',i)):= get(paste0('v',i+1))+2 ][]
  },
  lapply(1:2, function(i) dt3[ is.na(get(paste0('v',i))), (paste0('v',i)):= get(paste0('v',i+1))+2 ]),
  for(j in 1:2) {
    i1 <- which(is.na(dt4[[j]]))
    set(dt4, i = i1, j = j, value = dt[[j+1]][i1]+ 2)
  }  
)

Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                   expr      min       lq      mean   median
    for (i in 1:2) {     dt[is.na(get(paste0("v", i))), `:=`((paste0("v", i)), get(paste0("v",          i + 1)) + 2)] } 8.439924 8.651308 10.257670 8.900500
 for (i in 1:2) {     dt2[is.na(get(paste0("v", i))), `:=`((paste0("v", i)), get(paste0("v",          i + 1)) + 2)][] } 8.902435 9.098875 10.469305 9.262659
     lapply(1:2, function(i) dt3[is.na(get(paste0("v", i))), `:=`((paste0("v",      i)), get(paste0("v", i + 1)) + 2)]) 1.032788 1.144117  1.561741 1.224858
           for (j in 1:2) {     i1 <- which(is.na(dt4[[j]]))     set(dt4, i = i1, j = j, value = dt[[j + 1]][i1] + 2) } 6.216452 6.392754  7.970074 6.502356
       uq       max neval
 9.588571 35.259060   100
 9.729876 23.245224   100
 1.349337  9.467026   100
 7.046646 30.857044   100
```

Checking results are equivalent:

```r
identical(dt,dt2)
# [1] TRUE
identical(dt,dt3)
# [1] TRUE
identical(dt,dt4)
# [1] TRUE
```

There's probably more elegant way to do that but a division by 10 of mean computation time for something that only took a few seconds to program is a good yield ;)

Comment: thanks linog. seems to be faster also than the above proposed "set()" method. the dt object seems to be changed directly while executing the lapply(..) piece, so it seems i wouldn't even need to extract the output like this. (i just want to keep working with the manipulated columns in dt directly).

Comment: Nice ! Yes, you're right, I did not think about looking back at `dt`.  `:=` changes by reference your original `data.table` indeed. I added the `set` solution proposed by @akrun to the benchmark because it can interest other people too. If the answer suits you, could you accept it ?

Comment: sorry, I think I have to side with @akrun. I also added set() to the benchmark test and got the same result as you.. but: I then tested it on my real data set and set() seems much faster on "big data." intuitively this seems to make sense since your "lapply" method seems to generate a lot of overhead (think all the copies of dt for each element lapply goes through). if the data is very large, this seems to add up. it's a pity because the get()-syntax (with loop or lapply alike) appears much more readable/intuitive to me...

anyway, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Ok no problem that's nice to know. As I was saying, there's more elegant solution than a `lapply` ;)